# How to get the Integer value of a column in .withColumn function? [Spark - Scala]

Tags: scala, date, dataframe, apache-spark

I need to use `date_add()` function to add 90 days to a dataframe's column. The function works correctly, but only when I hardcode the 90. If the number is in another column and I refer it, the function asks me for an integer to work.

This code works:

```
.withColumn("DATE_SUM_COLUMN",date_add(col("DATE_COLUMN"),90))
```

This code does not:

```
.withColumn("DATE_SUM_COLUMN",date_add(col("DATE_COLUMN"),col("number")))
```

Thanks.

Comment: which version of spark?

Comment: @undefined_variable the version is 2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still may use `expr("date_add(date_column, days_to_add)")` function to evaluate a Spark SQL string:

```
import java.sql.Date

import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.{DataFrameSuiteBase, SharedSparkContext}
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

class TestSo2 extends FlatSpec with SharedSparkContext with DataFrameSuiteBase {
  "date_add" should "add number of dates specified as Column" in {
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = Seq(
      (Date.valueOf("2019-01-01"), 31),
      (Date.valueOf("2019-01-01"), 32)
    ).toDF("date_column", "days_to_add")
    df.show()

    /**
     * +-----------+-----------+
     * |date_column|days_to_add|
     * +-----------+-----------+
     * | 2019-01-01|         31|
     * | 2019-01-01|         32|
     * +-----------+-----------+
     */

    df.
      withColumn(
        "next_date",
        expr("date_add(date_column, days_to_add)")
      ).
      show

    /**
     * +-----------+-----------+----------+
     * |date_column|days_to_add| next_date|
     * +-----------+-----------+----------+
     * | 2019-01-01|         31|2019-02-01|
     * | 2019-01-01|         32|2019-02-02|
     * +-----------+-----------+----------+
     */
  }
}
```

I don't know the reasons why spark developers have not made it as a part of Scala API though.

Comment: what if its a string column? I want to do replaceAll() on all the col strings

Comment: @ss301: Not sure if I get your question. You may use spark's `regexp_replace()` function function to replace all matches according to regexp.

Comment: ya thanks, i did that regexp_replace(col("column_name"), lit("[^ -~]"), lit(""))) replaces all non printable characters

Answer (score 2):

Please try this here I am converting date to seconds, converting days column to seconds and summing the two columnsns. Again we have to convert the final result to date format. Here `date` is my date column, `add` is days to add for the date column

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

.withColumn("new col", unix_timestamp($"date", "yyyy-MM-dd") + col("add")*24*60*60)
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the update. Please check now, This solution might not optimal but as of now, I got this only. Will look for optimal

Comment: The result is in timestamp format, I would have to cast again to a date format. Maybe is a little tricky solution, but it resolves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Again we have to convert to the required date format, I mentioned above that one. Thanks for update